# How can I pass parameter to remote command in a treetable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to pass parameter **node** to the function **doAction** which will be invoked by the remote command, how can I pass it? Suppose **node** has attributes **name** and **type** and I want to use them in doAction, how can I pass the variables?

Thanks!

```
public static class node {
        String name;
        String type;

        //setters getters etc...
}

<p:remoteCommand name="doWhatYouWant" action="#{managedBean.doAction}" />

<p:treeTable value="#{managedBean.tree}" var="node">
<p:column>
        <p:commandLink value="Invoke action"  onclick="doWhatYouWant([params...])" />
</p:column>
</p:tree>

public void doAction() {
        // do something with var="node"
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of doAction and the format you are using for the params.

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking the problem or I don't understand your concern. You can easily just pass the argument with an `<f:param/>` within the `<p:commandLink/>` tag and pickup the parameters in the backing bean method, the same way you'd do any other parameter

Comment: Or even easier: forget about `<p:remoteCommand>` and directly call `<p:commandLink action="doWhatYouWant(someVar)" />` and in your managed bean you should have `public void doWhatYouWant(ClassOfSomeVar someVar) { ... }`. Really, I don't know what you're working in but I highly recommend you to stop that and to **learn** JSF, the basics and then start using the power of third party libraries as PrimeFaces, otherwise you'll be posting lot of more questions with common solutions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you for your advice but commandLink action simply doesn't work in treeTable.

Comment: It works, I've made examples about this in production application. The problem here is that you're not posting the whole picture and doing whatever you think it could be good. I recommend you **one more time** to learn JSF basics, and then do this exercise in a plain simple page that will **only** contain your `<p:dataTable>` and a `<p:column>` with `<p:commandLink value="Invoke action" action="doWhatYouWant(param)" />`.

Comment: Thank you and I'm always learning. But here I'm using treeTable instead of dataTable, and there are a lot of people discussing ways to make commandLink work inside treeTable on Primefaces forum.

Comment: I ended up using the remoteCommand. But stuck at the problem of passing parameters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza were you working with treeTable commandLinks? Could you show me your example? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem with

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="doWhatYouWant" action="#{managedBean.doAction}" />
 ...
 <p:commandLink value="Invoke action"  
     onclick="doWhatYouWant(
           [{name:'n', value:'#{node.name}'},
            {name:'t', value:'#{node.type}'}])" />
```

In the supporting bean:

```
public void doAction() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String name = map.get("n"); // name attribute of node
    String type = map.get("t"); // type attribute of node  
    ...
}
```